# Computations in the exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I want to be able to compute with explicit exterior algebras of vector spaces. For example, given a real vector space $V$ of $3 \times 3$ matrices, I want to consider expressions of the form $v\wedge w\in \Lambda^2 V$ and would like Mathematica to understand that $v\wedge w=-w\wedge v$, and $v\wedge w+v\wedge t=v\wedge (w+t)$ etc. In particular, I want to be able to define linear operators on $\Lambda^2 V$ on a basis of decomposable elements and extend it by linearity to all elements. As an example, I would like to define an inner product $$B(x\wedge y,z\wedge w)=\langle x,y\rangle \langle z,w\rangle-\langle x,w\rangle\langle y,z\rangle$$ and have Mathematica understand that $$B(e_1\wedge e_2+e_3\wedge e_4,e_1\wedge e_2-e_3\wedge e_4)=0,$$ where $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\in V$ are orthonormal.

So far, my attempts were tricking Mathematica into thinking that $v\wedge w$ is the ordered pair `{v,w}`, but the problem is that this only makes computations work for *decomposable* vectors, since it thinks that $e_1\wedge e_2+e_3\wedge e_4=(e_1+e_3)\wedge (e_2+ e_4)$, i.e., `{e1,e2}+{e3,e4}={e1+e3,e2+e4}`, but I want to rule this out.

The command `\wedge` in Mathematica does not have a meaning (only makes for a nice display), and I tried using `TensorWedge[,]` but I can't get it to answer back results of expressions explicitly. I also gave a couple Packages a try, like "Grassmann" and "Ricci", but I feel there should be an easier way of doing this... Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't have v9, so I'm not sure, but it looks like `Normal` and declaring your symbols to be vectors using `$Assumptions` may be what you need. Check out the example for `TensorWedge` [here](http://wolfram.com/xid/0b8c12b4xm-b3gk17). What do you think?

Comment: I suspect that listability of `Plus` will play havoc with any attempt to represent the operation as an ordered `List`. Also, might try some ideas from the nb available [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/), in the section "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation".

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we work with objects in some symbolic dimension dim:

```
In[1]:= $Assumptions = (e[1] | e[2] | e[3] | e[4]) \[Element] Vectors[dim]  
           && (a | b) \[Element] Matrices[{dim, dim}, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]];
```

Now we can do something like

```
In[2]:= TensorRank[e[1]\[TensorWedge]e[2]]
Out[2]= 2
```

and basic manipulations like

```
In[3]:= a\[TensorWedge](a + 2 b) // TensorExpand
Out[3]= a\[TensorWedge]a + 2 a\[TensorWedge]b

In[4]:= e[1]\[TensorWedge]e[2] + e[2]\[TensorWedge]e[1] // TensorReduce
Out[4]= 0

In[5]:= a\[TensorWedge]b + a\[TensorWedge]b // TensorReduce
Out[5]= 2 a\[TensorWedge]b
```

We can define your scalar product as follows:

```
In[6]:= vectorQ[v_] := SameQ[TensorRank[v], 1];

In[7]:= B[TensorWedge[v1_?vectorQ, v2_?vectorQ], 
          TensorWedge[v3_?vectorQ, v4_?vectorQ]] := v1.v2 v3.v4 - v1.v4 v2.v3
```

We also need linearity relations:

```
In[8]:= B[x_Plus, y_] := B[#, y] & /@ x;
        B[x_, y_Plus] := B[x, #] & /@ y;
        B[c_?NumberQ x_, y_] := c B[x, y];
        B[x_, c_?NumberQ y_] := c B[x, y];
```

Finally:

```
In[12]:= B[e[1]\[TensorWedge]e[2] + e[3]\[TensorWedge]e[4], 
           e[1]\[TensorWedge]e[2] - e[3]\[TensorWedge]e[4]] // TensorExpand
Out[12]= 0
```

Orthonormality of the basis was not required for that. You can impose it as

```
In[13]:= e /: e[i_].e[j_] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]

In[14]:= Outer[Dot, {e[1], e[2]}, {e[1], e[2]}]
Out[14]= {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
```