# Exterior products of differential forms

Tags: tensors, code-request, differential-geometry

In $ \mathbb{R}^4 $ I have the forms $ \omega_1=z\;\mathrm dx+t\;\mathrm dy+x\;\mathrm dz+y\;\mathrm dt $ and $ \omega_2=t\;\mathrm dx+z\;\mathrm dy+y\;\mathrm dz+x\;\mathrm dt$.

I want to compute with Mathematica $ \omega_1\wedge\omega_2 $. I don't know how to declare a 1-form or 2-form and how to make their exterior product. Can someone write the code for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`TensorWedge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorWedge.html).

Comment: Might be [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37802/computations-in-the-exterior-algebra).